# How to get a Jenkins credential in a pipeline based on username part of the desired credential?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

Is there a way to get a Jenkins credential based on its username instead of credential ID? My credential is of type username/password with a global scope.

I have a use case where I know what the username is (based on a JSON file where username is stored but it could also be hardcoded in jenkinsFile) and I need to dynamically grap the corresponding password from Jenkins credentials store.

```
stage("Execute command based on schema"){
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: I_DONT_HAVE_THIS, passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'SCHEMA'])){
        sh "sqlplus \"$SCHEMA/$PASSWORD@DBNAME\" @/path/to/script.sql" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve credentials in Jenkins, you have to give the `credentialsId`, then you set the variable name for `username` and `password`. They will be linked to the appropriate username and password stored in the credentials manager.

With that, if credentials are correctly stored in Jenkins, you can set the username as `id` for the credential to retrieve the correct username and password.

I think this is possible for your use case because you have to store credentials before running your pipeline and you can set the `id` as you want.

**EDIT** *with a workaround*

If you really want to get credential using `username`, you can use a workaround to get the list of all credentials and match the appropriate `username` :

```
stage("Execute command based on schema") {
    steps {
        script {
            // Set this variable which should match with the user in credentials
            def schema = "usertest"
            def credential_id = ""
            def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
                com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
                Jenkins.instance,
                null,
                null
            );
            for (c in creds) {
                if (c.username == schema) {
                    credential_id = c.id
                }
            }
                
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: credential_id, passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'SCHEMA')]) {
                sh 'sqlplus \"$SCHEMA/$PASSWORD@DBNAME\" @/path/to/script.sql'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that there is some security issues :

- You will need to activate a lot of script in the administrator side (see [script-approval](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/))
- Anyone who can access to the script can call, in the loop, all credential field like `id`, `description`, `username` and `password` (thay will **not be masked**)
- You should manage errors in case the `username` doesn't match with any credentials

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have used this workaround before but really need to double check if there is a way to select Jenkins credential based on username or other credential field value (not credentialId)

Comment: See my edit with a workaround wich should match with your use case.

Comment: It works like a charme. Thanks for pointing possible caveats and security implications. In my case it seems like somehow " com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
  com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class" script signature was already approved as this did not blocked script execution. Gathered credential are still masked in build console (which is good). Of course I'll have to deal with possible duplicated credential entries with same username OR missing one.